# How to check if a large binary file contains the contents of another one?

Tags: files, binary

I have a large binary file e.g. a WAV file which I suspect might contain the whole sequence of bytes of a smaller WAV file.

How do I check if it does? If it does, how do I find the starting position?

Something like:

```
$ findguts big.wav small.wav
1234 # the contents of small.wav are found inside big.wav starting at byte #1234
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
perl -l -0777 -ne '
  print "found at offset $o" if ($o = index($_, <STDIN>)) >= 0
  ' big.wav < small.wav
```

(note that both files are loaded in memory, so it doesn't scale to very large files).

Comment: Probably, we should consider the header of such files, e.g. for [WAV](https://docs.fileformat.com/audio/wav/) I see that first 44 bytes is the header, which is file dependent (e.g. last part is the file size) so it seems meaningful to exclude it before search, with a tail or anything. (without having any idea about the wav format)